# How to extract customer and products ordered statistics in web site with python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, numpy, nosql

To get the statistical behavior of buyers and visitors to a store site and process the numbers obtained from the number of visits, number of purchases and other similar items regardless of what language or database the site is using in the background, from which libraries in Python and  How can it be used?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use beautifulsoup package.Also you need to import requests for website access.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

After that store your base URL and define the header like the following:

```
baseurl1 = 'website url'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36'}
```

This is the staring. You should explore more. If you are stuck anywhere then StackOverflow is here!!